# Python: Change class type name

Tags: python

How would you change a class type name to something other than classobj?

```
class bob():
    pass

foo = bob
print "%s" % type(foo).__name__
```

which gets me 'classobj'.

Comment: Please explain why `classobj` is not a good type name for an old-style class, and why you need to change that. Note that for new-style classes ("class bob(object):") the type name is `type`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your example, you've defined `foo` as a reference to the class definition of `bob`, not to an instance of bob. The type of an (old-style) class is indeed `classobj`.

If you instantiate `bob`, on the other hand, the result will be different:

```
# example using new-style classes, which are recommended over old-style
class bob(object):
    pass

foo = bob()
print type(foo).__name__
'bob'
```

If you just want to see the name of the `bob` type without instantiating it, use:

```
print bob.__name__
'bob'
```

This works because `bob` is already a class type, and therefore has a `__name__` property that you can query.

Answer (score 12):

```
class DifferentTypeName(type): pass

class bob:
  __metaclass__ = DifferentTypeName

foo = bob
print "%s" % type(foo).__name__
```

emits `DifferentTypeName`, as you require.  It seems unlikely that this is actually what you want (or need), but, hey, it *is* the way to do exactly what you so explicitly **ask** for: change a class's `type`'s name.  Assigning a suitable renamed derivative of `type` to `foo.__class__` or `bob.__class__` later would also work, so you could encapsulate this into a pretty peculiar function:

```
def changeClassTypeName(theclass, thename):
  theclass.__class__ = type(thename, (type,), {})

changeClassTypeName(bob, 'whatEver')

foo = bob
print "%s" % type(foo).__name__
```

this emits `whatEver`.

Comment: Brilliant, if very very horrifying, answer to a strange question.

Comment: @eblume: Not completely crazy.  Perhaps the OP was creating a function that constructed classes.  I suppose that would be called a meta-factory, since a factory constructs instances.  Some enum implementations, for example, might want a unique class name for each enum type, so that `enum('Days', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')` returns an instance of a new class Days, with members Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun.

Comment: @Deep in that case you're probably best off calling the 3 arg version of `type` directly. Modifying `__class__` is still evil.