# Python: Changing the class name

Tags: python, class

In Python I'm making a graph class which I intend to design by creating a Node class, and then an Edge class which takes as arguments to the constructor two nodes, a source and target.  I'd also like to check in the Edge class that the two inputs are in fact Nodes, so I'd like to include some lines like

```
assert type(src) is Node and type(tgt) is Node
```

However, this will not act as I expect it to.  As I understand it, I would need to use something like `src.__name__ is Node.__name__` but this just seems ugly.  Is there a way to control the type name of a user-defined class so that the code reads a little more nicely?

I tried following some of what I found here: [Python: Change class type name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850289/python-change-class-type-name#1850306)

and wrote the code

```
class Node: 
    ...
    __class__ = type("Node", (type,), {})
```

I'm not sure if I was mis-applying the lessons found in that link or if those lessons wouldn't accomplish what I'm trying to do--but one way or another, it didn't do what I was hoping for.

Comment: Why doesn't `type(src) is Node` work?

Comment: `assert type(src) is Node and type(tgt) is Node` *should* work, how does it not work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out "**isinstance**" built-in function:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance

Example:

```
>>> class Node(object):
...   pass
... 
>>> class Booger(object):  
...   pass
... 
>>> n=Node()
>>> b=Booger()
>>> isinstance(n, Node)
True
>>> isinstance(b, Node)
False
>>> 
>>> class SubNode(Node):
...   pass
... 
>>> sn=SubNode()
>>> isinstance(sn, Node)
True
```